# How to use custom domain name email with Firebase Hosting

Tags: angularjs, email, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am hosting [my Angular web app](https://atila.ca/) on Firebase under a custom domain name. I bought the domain name via Namecheap.

Now I would like to receive email with my custom domain. E.g. send and receive email from info@atila.ca. I have set it up in cPanel but when I try to send to this email I get the following error:

```
<info@atila.ca>: unknown user: "info@atila.ca"
Reporting-MTA: dns; eforward3e.registrar-servers.com
```

Is this a Firebase, or Namecheap or cpanel issue? Any advice on how to fix this please?

Answer (score 12):

Firebase doesn't currently support email, so pointing your nameservers to Firebase isn't enough to set up email for your custom domain.

What you will have to do is point email requests to an email provider, not Firebase. That way, your https traffic goes to Firebase, while emails go to the email provider. To 'point email requests to an email provider', you will have to add MX records into your DNS from the Namecheap admin dashboard. The MX records would point to a third party email provider such as [Zoho](https://www.zoho.eu/) - I'm using Zoho myself and it's free for up to 5GB of storage.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Another option for anyone else having this issue is that Namecheap offers a [email hosting solution](https://www.namecheap.com/hosting/email.aspx). The benefit is that all the dns configuration is handled for you, the downside is that you pay ~ $1/month.

Comment: Update: @Sebastian himself actually wrote a [blog post](https://ghetu.net/blog/keeping-your-custom-email-address-while-using-firebase-hosting/) on how to do this and There is a [Firebase google group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/Dr-jYjZ7cKY/kzldBzZSBAAJ) on this issue.

Comment: Zoho no longer offers email. Any alternative ?

Comment: @Emeric, One email option I'm considering is ProtonMail (no relationship with them, except an ordinary personal email account there): https://proton.me/pricing